# How does the Oracle (+) join work in this scenario

Tags: oracle, left-join

I have a question about Oracle's (+) left/right join in a scenario where the 2 tables were joined on 2 columns but one column was with (+) but the other was without the (+).  I am trying to convert a whole bunch of queries and changing them to the proper join and curious about this one.

The query using the (+) join works but when convert to a proper left/right join the results are different. See sample code.

--OLD

```
select *
from tbl1 a, tbl2 b
where a.col1 = b.col1 (+)
and a.col2 = b.col2
```

--CONVERTED

```
select *
from tbl1 a
left join tbl2 b on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2
```

Is there a way to make the CONVERTED code work just like the OLD?

Thanks.

RS..

Comment: What does "The query using the (+) join works" mean? The manual tells you what (+) does & what LEFT JOIN does. "If A and B are joined by multiple join conditions, then you must use the (+) operator in all of these conditions. If you do not, [...]" This question is asking us to write yet another presentation of (+) & LEFT JOIN plus a bespoke tutorial. That is too broad yet nevertheless a faq. Show that the results are not what some authoritative presentation says they are & we can tell you where you are going wrong. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a minimal reproducible example--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS What is stopping you from writing non-(+) code that does what old code that "works" does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query will not do `left outer join` but it will do `inner join` as there are condition without `(+)` that is why using new format of join is more suitable for readability and less complexity.

If you really want to stick to old join format that is using `(+)` then you can use the following code.

```
select *
from tbl1 a, tbl2 b
where a.col1 = b.col1 (+)
and a.col2 = b.col2 (+)
```

Above code will do proper `left outer join` as all the condition pertaining to the table are now tagged with `(+)`

BUT, It is recommended that you use new join format, that is, use `LEFT JOIN` syntax.

Hope, It will clear your doubts.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to convert to ANSI syntax, then you should know that your old query is executed as an **inner** join and not as an outer join. The converted query should be:

```
select *
  from tbl1 a
  join tbl2 b on (
       b.col1 = a.col1
   and b.col2 = a.col2
  )
```

If you think you have stumbled on a bug, and that the query should be executed as an outer join, then your query will be:

```
select *
  from tbl1      a
  left join tbl2 b on (
       b.col1 = a.col1
   and b.col2 = a.col2
  )
```

If you want to **repeat the same mistake** as the original query, i.e appearing to be an outer join while actually being executed as an inner join... the query will be:

```
select *
  from tbl1 a
  left join tbl2 b on (
       b.col1 = a.col1       
  )
 where b.col2 = a.col2
```